# Why can't I get good approximation when choosing values away from point of expansion? (Taylor series)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

I was in the middle of doing a computing project assigned to me when I came across the question.

$\operatorname{P}_N(x)$ is the taylor polynomial for $f(x)=\ln(x)$ expanded around pouint $x_0=1$

$$\operatorname{P}_N(x)=\sum^{N}_{i=1}\dfrac{(-1)^{i+1}}{i}(x-1)^i$$

Using a fortran 90, for values of $x$ close to 1 (the point of expansion) , the $\operatorname{P}_N(x)$ approximates the true value of $\ln{x}$(in-built function) well. However, if I take values of $x=10$, I get an error which increases as I take more iterations.

My question is,

1. Is there a range of values of $x$ such that $\operatorname{P}_N(x)$ converges to the true value of $\ln(x)$?
2. What is the point of expansion? How is it different expanding around $x=1$ and some other value of $x$?

Comment: Perhaps this article may be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, there is a range. It depends on the function and the expansion point. Sometimes it is infinite, but not in your case. Here it is $(0,2]$.
2. The point of expansion is the point around which you expand (1 in your case). If you expand around some other point, you'll get different series and (generally speaking) different range of convergence.